# How to sensitize users of this website to the "Be Nice" policy?

Tags: discussion

I'm not using this website very often but as far as I noticed it seems like the "Be Nice" policy of Stack Exchange is not enforced here as it is on other Stack websites. For example in [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25672/quest-ce-que-le-home-de-neige) you can see regular users of the website who seems to still haven't understood it (or don't care, but anyway the result is the same).

Shouldn't the moderation become more strict toward these persons?

Comment: In my opinion the first step to being nice is to take the time to read the questions to which one answers. Then we can talk...

Comment: Please, try to be contructive, if you have a valuable answer to this thread make it an answer, not a comment.

Comment: When someone lets you know in a correct manner that you're likely misunderstanding something, when someone was already told the same thing for the same reasons weeks before, when OPs take the time to comment their point of view & point to what still remain obscure for them in their question, one has to expect there might be a time when OPs will get frustrated at what might well be perceived to be a statement against their intelligence. Agreed, anger should not spill over, but downvoting their question for fallacious reasons after is not very helpful either and only adds fuel to the fire.

Comment: -1 because I only noticed ONE regular user of the website being not so nice. Mind you, there is a bit of a justification for this user not to be nice, but in the end, the count adds up to one only. You got your revenge through downvoting for bad reasons, that's good enough for me, and I would hope it would be good enough for you too!

Comment: @Feelew: on the thread I linked I can easily count two different people. And that's just one thread. Look, you even have an example with the passive-agressive comment on top of this very pile: "In my opinion the first step to being nice is to take the time to read the questions to which one answers. Then we can talk...". And that's even upvoted!

Comment: Trying to justify a down vote with the type of reasons you gave was also a bit misplaced, so yes, there might indeed have been two users that were not being nice to each other. However, it's quite unfair to state that Laure is being rude. Tired of someone trying too hard to prove their point and firing in every direction, perhaps (after all, I'm feeling it myself), but rude, NO! Please, can you just let it die. Something unpleasant happened, the mods deleted a whole bunch of comments and the waves have now receded. Let's move on and go back to what we like: the French language!

Comment: @Feelew: you may be interested in reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react). In my case it was the reason #4 in the first answer's nomenclature.

Comment: You know what my feelings are, I expressed them in a lot of different ways, this is it, I've had enough now and I'm outta here! Case closed! I'd rather forgive than choke through holding a grudge forever. All the best for you and I hope to see some constructive Q&A from you soon!

Answer (score 6):

If you notice that people are [not nice](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), please [flag](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the offending comments or posts, and **do not engage**.

When flagging, please keep in mind that the [moderators](https://french.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) are volunteers. We try to handle flags in a timely manner but we can't be watching the site 24/7.

Comment: I don't think I engaged here, did I? I keep that in mind, don't worry, but as I see someone being really rude with ~7k rep (or even 33k for Laure), I think there is a way more serious problem here than just slowness from mods.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Gilles was probably answering in a general way. So he didn't say that you did engage.

Comment: @Walfrat: my point is that this answer doesn't really apply to the specific case I am describing, so I can't really accept it.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Your question didn't refer to a specific case, you just pointed to a question (and were probably asking about some comments that have since been deleted, but you didn't say, and shouldn't have said). And the answer is: flag the offending comments.

Comment: @Gilles: the question is "I notice people being not nice on a regular basis, not just in a few comments, and not just newcomers". Your answer is "flag the offending comments", which is an answer to a different situation. About the deletion if I remember correctly you were the one to delete these comments, and it happened before I asked this question.

Comment: Also I realise I don't understand the part "but you didn't say, and shouldn't have said". What do you mean exactly?